# Словосочетания "пустой звук", "живой звук" это фразеологические единства, сращения или сочетания?

Tags: лексика, фразеология, словосочетания, метафора, лексикология

"Пустой" и "живой" можно трактовать по-разному. Части вроде заменимы (звук на музыку, пустой на бессмысленный), но смысл тогда меняется... Однако и фразеологическим сращением не назовешь... Поэтому предполагаю, что это единство фразеологическое. К тому же нет слов, которые не употребляются вне словосочетания.
Но все еще сомневаюсь.

Comment: мне кажется, "пустой звук" - единство, а живой звук - вообще не фразеологизм.